# actionbar setnavigationmode deprecated

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-menu

Hi I'm making an app in which I plan on showing floor & category wise listing of stores inside a mall.

Below snap show an activity showing floor wise listing of stores
[image]

I was thinking of adding a spinner in the ActionBar showing "by Floor" and "by Category" as options. Clicking on "by Category" would arrange the stores according to the category in which they belong. After googling a bit I found

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

would be apt but now I see that its deprecated, putting it as an action item in the activity menu doesn't look like a very good idea. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think that Google would steer you to a navigation drawer.

Comment: I have a navigation drawer but that lists Malls, Offers and events. This activity starts after clicking on a mall list item.

Comment: @VihaanVerma have you find the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 8):

setNavigationMode it's deprecated because on Lollipop it has being replaced by a new paradigm.

You have two options, at least:

1. Ignore it unless you are targeting 21+ API and developing only for Lollipop.
2. Use AppCompat; samples here: https://github.com/google/iosched

Personally, I went for option 1.

Comment: Just checked the google play music app. They have one option in activity menu for showing the list of currently playing songs. On toggle it shows a viewpager with current song. I think activity menu toggle action would be an okay way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The Google I/O 2014 Android App contain what you need

SlidingTabLayout.java ,check out [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)

and the SlidingTabStrip.java

there are two files could implement what you show up there.

more document about this style at [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs)