# AndroidRuntime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError my.package.CustomActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: java, android

I am using Eclipse as IDE. 
Android SDK Platform-tools 21 ( latest )

With the wizard I have added a "Navigation Drawer Activity". Next-> Next->... Finish.

Then I saw there are deprecated methods, I have checked already here and some are because is deprecated in API version 21 others are because the v4 is replaced with v7.

```
   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

I want to support the v15, without deprecations, and compile it with 5.0 ( I am not sure if that is a correct method or not)

I have changed the imports to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

as how it is suggested in other posts.

Also in `FragmentActivity` the `Activity`:

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks
```

Also changed:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
}
```

And added the ignore:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/27626971 : ignore, because it is not only for android 5.0
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

This class has no other changes versus the generated.

The NavigationDrawerFragment has a few changes. The imports has changed to above.

The `setUp()` declares an anonymous class that has been extracted and modified according to other SO post.

At this line it is the exception:

```
mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, getActivity(), mDrawerLayout);
```

Here is the class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment;

    public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment, Activity mActivity, DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
        super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        this.navigationDrawerFragment = navigationDrawerFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        if (!navigationDrawerFragment.isAdded()) {
            return;
        }

        navigationDrawerFragment.getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        if (!navigationDrawerFragment.isAdded()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!navigationDrawerFragment.isUserLearnedDrawer()) {
            // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
            // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
            navigationDrawerFragment.setUserLearnedDrawer(true);
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(navigationDrawerFragment.getActivity());
            sp.edit().putBoolean(NavigationDrawerFragment.PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
        }

        navigationDrawerFragment.getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

}
```

With File Import  I have imported from the SDK the `android-support-v7-appcompat` Marked as library and it compiles.

I have set the dependency to this project and marked at Order And Export.

I have copied the `android-support-v4.jar` from appcompat to my project to be the same version. Still the same exception at runtime.

I have added the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` from .bin directory ( the compiled one) to my project libs. Still the same error at runtime.

Before extracting the anonymous class the message it was NoClassDefFoundError android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle as  I remember - the parent class.

Yesterday wasted all day to figure out and ended in deleting and use deprecated methods, but  I would like to have a non deprecated version - if is possible.

Pls come with suggestion, which I didn't made already!

Comment: How did you solve it?