# ActionBar with Tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I can't use the method `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` on `ActionBar`. I don't understand why my Application doesn't run.
Isn't it supported by the library?

`actionBar.setNavigationMode.(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

Comment: Hi try with SlidingTab (for tab) class. Becz setNavigationMode deprected. Refer this link-https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626761/actionbar-setnavigationmode-deprecated

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020

Answer (score 0):

You should use the design support library TabLayout, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html. See http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html from the section Tabs:

> Tabs
>   Switching between different views in your app via tabs is not a new concept to material design and they are equally at home as a top level navigation pattern or for organizing different groupings of content within your app (say, different genres of music).
>
> The Design library’s TabLayout implements both fixed tabs, where the
>   view’s width is divided equally between all of the tabs, as well as
>   scrollable tabs, where the tabs are not a uniform size and can scroll
>   horizontally. Tabs can be added programmatically:

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
```

> However, if you
>   are using a ViewPager for horizontal paging between tabs, you can
>   create tabs directly from your PagerAdapter’s getPageTitle() and then
>   connect the two together using setupWithViewPager(). This ensures that
>   tab selection events update the ViewPager and page changes update the
>   selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine, you can try it. Hope it's helpful.

First, implements ActionBar.TabListener.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {}
```

then, setup in onCreate().

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    mPager.setPageMargin(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.page_margin));

    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getCount(); position++) {
        getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab()
                .setText(adapter.getPageTitle(position))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

override other,

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than actionbar navigation mode, I would like to suggest you to use this library.
[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Because actionbar navigation mode method supports api level 14 and greater than 14 but this library will support from android 2.3 and higher one.

Comment: You'd better to use TabLayout from android design support library